# 504 (Gateway Timeout) on AWS

Tags: php, ajax, apache, amazon-ec2, timeout

I have my web app running on AWS EC2 instance in PHP and I make an ajax call that takes about 5-10 mintes, I see the web console in Google Chrome and I get this  `504 (Gateway Timeout)` ,How I can increase the value of this, is that related to apache?
Thanks

Comment: Where did the 504 message originate - in Apache, in PHP, or in some kind of load balancer / CDN? What does your phpinfo() say next to "Server API"?

Comment: If you're running your call through PHP, you need to increase your [maximum execution time in php.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time).

Comment: @TML I strongly believe that it is due to ELB but not sure how to fix that

Comment: @matcarlson its in ELB because once I use instance URL that ajax call works fine

Answer (score 15):

ELB by default times out at 60 seconds; there is no way I know of to extend this limit, although [this page](http://harish11g.blogspot.com/2012/07/aws-elastic-load-balancing-elb-amazon.html) suggests that it's something Amazon Support can do for you (and also suggests a method of working around the problem):

> Point 6) Amazon ELB timeouts at 60 seconds (kept idle)
>
> Amazon ELB
>   currently timeouts persistent socket connections @ 60 seconds if it is
>   kept idle. This condition will be a problem for use cases which
>   generates large files (PDF, reports etc) at backend EC2, sends them as
>   response back and keeps connection idle during entire generation
>   process. To avoid this you'll have to send something on the socket
>   every 40 or so seconds to keep the connection active in Amazon ELB.
>   Note: I heard we can extend this value after explaining the case to
>   AWS support team.

Edit: As commenters below have pointed out, as of [July 24th, 2014](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/07/24/elastic-load-balancing-now-supports-idle-timeout-configuration/) this is configurable in your AWS console.

Comment: I've had success with getting the ELB timeout limit extended by asking before.  It's worth confirming (so you can relay to the AWS engineers) that your backend has a greater timeout than the timeout you're seeking to increase the ELB to.

Comment: @JeffSisson they extended it to 20 Minutes but what if the request takes more than 20 minutes?

Comment: @user1765876 If a request is taking that long, you are probably doing it wrong. Start using message queues.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to look into some kind of asynchronous operation, queueing being the general category here.  Heavy operations shouldn't be done on the request.

Comment: Idle timeout is now configurable! http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/07/24/elastic-load-balancing-now-supports-idle-timeout-configuration/

Answer (score 0):

Do you tried change the timeout on ELB?
Increase the inactivity limit connection inside Load Balancer Atrributes. Then you can change the default limit form 60 to 120.

Comment: This was already suggested by the other answer. What's new?

Answer (score 0):

There is a related question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58017214/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-controller-returns-504-error).
Ensure you are doing the following (from this related question):

> 1. I've confirmed that the containers/pods are running,
> 2. the application has started and
> 3. if I exec into the pod then I can run a local curl command and get a response
>    from the app.
> 4. I've checked the logs on the ingress pods and traffic is arriving

Some useful commands for this [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-cluster-connection/) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/).

Next step is to increase the ELB idle time as mentioned in the previous answer.
In case you are using terraform you can use in annotations of your ingress:

```
"alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes" = "idle_timeout.timeout_seconds=600"
```

Usually there is an NGINX ingress controller on top of that ELB that helps directing the traffic to your services.
The latter also has timeouts, usually at 60 seconds.
You need to change its timeouts as specified [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#custom-timeouts).
If you are using terraform you can specify them in your ingress annotations like so (changed them from 60 to 300 seconds):

```
  "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout" = "10"
  "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout" = "300"
  "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout" = "300"
```

You can then shell into your ingress controller as explained in link 2 and 3 and check your nginx.conf file. The new limits should be applied.